# Integral $\int\limits_a^b\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}$ using Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

> Evaluate $\displaystyle \int\limits_a^b\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2},$ where $0<a<b$, using Riemann sums.

*Attempt.* Since $1/x^2$ is decreasing, it is integrable and using Riemann sums we get:
$$\int\limits_a^b\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\big(a+k\,\frac{b-a}{n}\big)^2}.$$
Is it possible to get a formula for the above sum?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky: you may approximate
$$ n(b-a) \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(na+k(b-a))^2} $$
with
$$ n(b-a) \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(na+k(b-a))(na+(k+1)(b-a))} $$
which is a telescopic sum, equal to
$$ n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\frac{1}{na+k(b-a)}-\frac{1}{na+(k+1)(b-a)}\right]=n\left[\frac{1}{na+(b-a)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)b-a}\right] $$
whose limit as $n\to +\infty$ is $\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}$. You may check that the difference between the actual Riemann sum and its telescopic approximation is $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, hence we have just proved
$$ \int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b} $$
(for $b>a>0$) by creative telescoping.

Comment: The approximation by a telescopic sum was the key. Great approach.